# Display web image in android

Tags: android

I try to load a jpg image in a image view but I can't get the image, I debug the code and I guess to have some issue with permissions but when I try from another public web I have the same problem.

I use this 2 examples published here but I can find where is my error, very thanks for the help!

```
//option 1
    private static Drawable fotoWeb(String address) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(address).getContent(); 
            //this line don't work crash on getContent()
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "Foto");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

//option 2
    private static Bitmap fotoBMP (String address){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(60000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(65000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect(); //this line don't work crash on connect()
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
            return bmpImage;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I better use the Picasso  Library with the result I want very thanks GoRos for the help here is the link I use to see how to use http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine, just ensure to add the internet permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Much more simplified and enough:

```
public static Bitmap fotoBMP(String address) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes very thanks for help me but already have internet permission

Comment: there is some error in connection.connect(); and i can't fixed, I gone try to download the image file to sdcard maybe that works, but if you find some other way to fix these I very thanks for your answer.